# Prob. 10, Sec. 30, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: A countable product of separable spaces is also separable

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separable-spaces

Here is Prob. 10, Sec. 30, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that if $X$ is a countable product of spaces having countable dense subsets, then $X$ has a countable dense subset.

My Attempt:

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ be any countably many topological spaces having countable dense subsets $D_1, D_2, D_3, \ldots$, respectively, and let us put
>   $$ \mathbf{X} \colon= X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 \times \cdots. \tag{Definition 0} $$
>
> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $p_n$ be some given point of $X_n$.
>
> Now let us put 
>   $$ D_{n_1, \ldots, n_r}^\prime \colon= D_1^\prime \times D_2^\prime \times D_3^\prime \times \cdots, \tag{Definition 1} $$
>   where $D_n^\prime \colon= D_n$ for finitely many $n = n_1, \ldots, n_r$, and $D_n \colon= \left\{ p_n \right\}$ for all other valuse of $n$.
>
> Then let 
>   $$ \mathbf{D} \colon= \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n_1, \ldots, n_r \in \mathbb{N}} D_{n_1, \ldots, n_r}^\prime. \tag{Definition 2} $$
>
> The set $\mathbf{D}$ is a countable union of countable subsets of $\mathbf{X}$ and is thus itself a countable subset of $\mathbf{X}$.
>
> We now show that $\mathbf{D}$ is dense in $\mathbf{X}$, that is, we show that 
>   $$ \overline{\mathbf{D}} = \mathbf{X}. \tag{0} $$
>
> Let $\mathbf{x} \colon= x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3 \times \cdots$ be any point of $X$, and let 
>   $$ \mathbf{B} \colon= B_1 \times B_2 \times B_3 \times \cdots \tag{Definition 3} $$
>   be any basis set for the product topology on $X$ such that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{B}$; let $n = n_1, \ldots, n_r$ be the finitely many indices for which $B_n$ is an open set of $X_n$ and let $B_n = X_n$ for all other values of $n$.
>
> For each $i = 1, \ldots, r$, as $D_{n_i}$ is dense in $X_{n_i}$ that is $\overline{D_{n_i}} = X_{n_i}$, so $x_{n_i} \in \overline{D_{n_i}}$, and since $B_{n_i}$ is an open set of $X_{n_i}$ containing $x_{n_i}$, therefore we can conclude that 
>   $$ B_{n_i} \cap D_{n_i} \neq \emptyset, \tag{1} $$ 
>   and thus there exists a point $y_{n_i} \in X_{n_i}$ such that
>   $$ y_{n_i} \in B_{n_i} \cap D_{n_i}. \tag{Definition 4*} $$
>
> Now let 
>   $$ \mathbf{y} \colon= y_1^\prime \times y_2^\prime \times y_3^\prime \times \cdots \in X, \tag{Definition 4} $$
>   where $y_{n_i}^\prime \colon= y_{n_i}$ for $i = 1, \ldots, r$, and $y_n^\prime \colon= p_n$ for all other values of $n$.
>
> This point $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbf{B} \cap \mathbf{D}$. [Please refer to (Definition 2), (Definition 3), and (Definition 4), and (Definition 4*)  above. ] Thus 
>   $$ \mathbf{B} \cap \mathbf{D} \neq \emptyset. \tag{2} $$
>
> Thus for any basis set $\mathbf{B}$ for the product topology on $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{B}$, the relation (2) above holds. Thus we can conclude that
>   $$ \mathbf{x} \in \overline{\mathbf{D}}. $$
>
> But as $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{X}$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that (0) above holds.
>
> Thus $\mathbf{X}$ has a countable dense subset $\mathbf{D}$. [Please refer to (Definition 0) and (Definition 2) above.]

Is this proof correct? If so, is my presentation clear enough? Or, are there errors or issues?

Comment: You don't really need $\Bbb x$ if the definition of dense is "intersects every non-empty open"

Answer (score 3):

You're way overcomplicating it. Just define

$$
\mathbf{D}= \left\{ \left(x_n \right)_n \in \mathbf{X}: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n: n \le N : x_n \in D_n \text{ and } \forall n > N x_n = p_n \right\}.
$$  That is, let
$$
\mathbf{D} \colon= \bigcup_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } 
\left( D_1 \times \cdots \times D_n \times \left\{ p_{n+1} \right\} \times \left\{ p_{n+2} \right\} \times \cdots \right)
$$
which is countable (it's another way of describing your set) and intersects all non-empty basic open sets and so is dense.

Comment: I have just added some detail to your answer. Do you agree to it? Is this the set you've meant?